# PHP and Last.fm API

Tags: php, json, last.fm

I have a JSON structure such as http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=XXXX&format=json and I'd like to pick out various bits of information such as similar artists (names and images), tags, the extralarge image, content etc

I got the similar arists working by using

```
<?php

$url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Queens%20Of%20the%20STone%20Age&api_key=XXX&format=json';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['artist']['similar']['artist'] as $item) {
    print $item['name'];
    print '<br>';
}
?>
```

However, how do I extract the "large" image from the following:

```
"artist": [{
     "name": "Them Crooked Vultures",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Them+Crooked+Vultures",
       "image": [{
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34\/38985285.jpg",
            "size": "small"
            }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64\/38985285.jpg",
            "size": "medium"
            }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/126\/38985285.jpg",
            "size": "large"
       }]
```

Thanks,

JJ

ALL SORTED! Finished product: http://www.strictlyrandl.com/artist/queens-of-the-stone-age/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the images and print it:

```
foreach($json['artist']['similar']['artist'] as $item) {
    print $item['name'];
    print '<br>';

    for ($i=0; $i < count($item['image']); $i++) { 
        echo $item['image'][$i]['#text']."<br>";
    }
}
```

To print them only if they're of size large or extra large, you can use a simple `if` statement:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($item['image']); $i++) { 
    echo $item['image'][$i]['#text']."<br>";
    if($item['image'][$i]['size'] == 'extralarge') {
        echo $item['image'][$i]['#text']."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's 5 different images for each artist - how do I pick out the one where size is large or extralarge (see updated question)

Comment: I figured it out in the end - ha! However I would have thought there was a way to access the value prior or at least not have to loop through every element i.e. is there a more efficient way. Thanks :-)

Comment: @JanuszJasinski: This is as efficient as it gets. You'll need a loop if you want to get *all* the URLs in the given JSON response. However, if you only want a particular one, you can directly access the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$get = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Cher&api_key=63692beaaf8ba794a541bca291234cd3&format=json');
$get = json_decode($get);
echo '<pre>';
//print_r($get->artist);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<strong>Artist Name = </strong>'.$get->artist->name.'<br/>
<strong>Artist mbid = </strong>'.$get->artist->mbid.'<br/>
<strong>Artist Url = </strong>'.$get->artist->url.'<br/>
<strong>Artist İmage = </strong><br/>';
foreach($get->artist->image as $image) {
$image = (array) $image;
    echo 'İmage Text = '.$image['#text'].'<br />
        İmage Size = '.$image['size'].'<br />';
}
```