# jQuery or PHP to Parse and Filter JSON, Outputting Certain Nodes Only

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here's a snippet of my JSON file

```
[{
        "id" : "61344",
        "bandappname" : null,
        "stageID" : "637",
        "title" : "The band title",
        "description" : "Some description",
        "date" : "Friday 22nd August",
        "time" : "23:00",
        "stageName" : "name of the stage",
        "startTime" : 1408662000,
        "endTime" : 1408662060,
        "weather" : {
            "iconcode" : "04n",
            "desc" : "broken clouds",
            "temp" : 17
        },
        "rating" : 0,
        "starstyle" : "",
        "userrating" : 0,
        "rated" : false,
        "plannercount" : 3,
        "eventimage" : "image.jpg",
        "lastupdated" : "1407413423",
        "activityid" : null,
        "activityliked" : null
    }
]
```

There's a few hundred nodes like this. There are 3 **dates** available (6th element down) and around 8 **stageID**'s (3rd element down)

So I am thinking of creating 24 DIVs to house each unique date/stage combination.

So my question is, for each div, how would I output the following, relevant to the DIV (stageID and date), in descending order (where title and time is the actual value)

```
title - time
title - time
title - time
...
title - time
```

I've tried looking at [PHP and Last.fm API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713627/php-and-last-fm-api) and various other StackOverflow posts but have returned to a blank page. My major problem is not knowing how to loop through the nodes

Can the DIVs be create automatically - does it have to be static? Should I use jQuery or PHP?

I got this far with jQuery but I am not sure how to order the items in each div based on `element.startTime`

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JSON</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

function convertUnix (unix) {
    newDate = new Date(unix *1000)  
    var curr_hour = newDate.getHours();
    var curr_min = newDate.getMinutes();
    var convertedTime = curr_hour + ":" + curr_min;
    return convertedTime
}

$.getJSON('json.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        var titleTime = "(" + element.startTime + ") "+ element.title + " - " + convertUnix(element.startTime) + " - " + convertUnix(element.endTime);

        if (element.date=='Friday 22nd August') {
            $('div#'+element.stageID+'-1').append($('<p>', {text: titleTime}));
        }
        if (element.date=='Saturday 23rd August') {
            $('div#'+element.stageID+'-2').append($('<p>', {text: titleTime}));
        }
        if (element.date=='Sunday 24th August') {
            $('div#'+element.stageID+'-3').append($('<p>', {text: titleTime}));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style> 
div {border:1px solid black; width:30%; float:left; background-color:#ccc; padding:20px; margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:20px;}
div:nth-child(3n) {clear:both; margin-bottom:20px;}
</style>
</body>

<div id="643-1"></div>
<div id="643-2"></div>
<div id="643-3"></div>

<div id="644-1"></div>
<div id="644-2"></div>
<div id="644-3"></div>

<div id="642-1"></div>
<div id="642-2"></div>
<div id="642-3"></div>

<div id="641-1"></div>
<div id="641-2"></div>
<div id="641-3"></div>

<div id="640-1"></div>
<div id="640-2"></div>
<div id="640-3"></div>

<div id="639-1"></div>
<div id="639-2"></div>
<div id="639-3"></div>

<div id="638-1"></div>
<div id="638-2"></div>
<div id="638-3"></div>

<div id="637-1"></div>
<div id="637-2"></div>
<div id="637-3"></div></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_str = '[{
        "id" : "61344",
        "bandappname" : null,
        "stageID" : "637",
        "title" : "The band title",
        "description" : "Some description",
        "date" : "Friday 22nd August",
        "time" : "23:00",
        "stageName" : "name of the stage",
        "startTime" : 1408662000,
        "endTime" : 1408662060,
        "weather" : {
            "iconcode" : "04n",
            "desc" : "broken clouds",
            "temp" : 17
        },
        "rating" : 0,
        "starstyle" : "",
        "userrating" : 0,
        "rated" : false,
        "plannercount" : 3,
        "eventimage" : "image.jpg",
        "lastupdated" : "1407413423",
        "activityid" : null,
        "activityliked" : null
    }
]';

$arr = json_decode($json_str);

echo $arr['stageID']." ".$arr['title']." ".$arr['date']." ".$arr['time'];
```